# Many to many relation return object null but right id

Tags: entity-framework-core

thanks for your help

two class:

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AuthorBook> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<AuthorBook> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorBook
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

DataContext

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    // public DbSet<AuthorBook> AuthorBooks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorBook>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.AuthorId, t.BookId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorBook>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Author)
            .WithMany(w => w.Books)
            .HasForeignKey(h => h.AuthorId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorBook>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Book)
            .WithMany(w => w.Authors)
            .HasForeignKey(h => h.BookId);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAuthors()
{
    var authors = await this.context.Authors.Include(i => i.Books).ToListAsync();
    return Ok(authors);
}
```

returns

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Paul",
    "books": [
        {
            "authorId": 1,
            "bookId": 2,
            "book": null
        },
        {
            "authorId": 1,
            "bookId": 5,
            "book": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Why authorId, bookId are Ok but can't access directly to the objet book (is null) ???

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're including the `Books` Navigation Property which is the Author's collection of `AuthorBook`, not `Book`.

```
public List<AuthorBook> Books { get; set; }
```

The actual `Book` records are another Navigation step away. To get them as well, you need to `.ThenInclude()` them:

```
var authors = await this.context.Authors
    .Include(i => i.Books)
    .ThenInclude(i => i.Book) 
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you, it's the solution !